# Positioning an div so it looks like a tab

Tags: css, html, positioning

I have a div within a div. I want one to extend out of the shell div so it resembles a tab. I thought just using absolute positioning with a negative value would push it out of the parent div. That doesn't seem to work. Is there a CSS work-around?

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/W3CyT/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/W3CyT/4/

CSS

```
#sideWall {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top: 10;
    left: 10;
    background: black;
    margin-top: 60px; /* give room for tab */
}

.showSideWall {
    height: 60px;
    width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -60px; /* move tab above container */
    right: 0;
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're doing it correctly, however, you need to rethink your values for `bottom` and `right`.

If you're looking to have the red box protrude from the black box on its right side, consider removing `right:0` and applying `left:100%` instead. This approach guarantees that no matter how wide the black box and red box are, the red box will always be on the outside to the right; they are width-size agnostic. This can be ideal because you may want to change the size of either box dynamically or in the future (it doesn't lock you in to hard set values).

[Here's a fiddle of what I'm talking about.](http://jsfiddle.net/W3CyT/7/)

Comment: I've tried positive and negative values, ridiculous and reasonable ones too. All it does is either line up on the right edge of the parent div or the left edge. I can get it to do anything else.

Comment: @Layne Also note that your values for the black box, `top` and `left`, are incomplete values. Add "px" to move them down and out.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Z-Index and position one on top of another. There is a better way to do it with Twitter bootstrap code.

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

they give you templates for all kinds of cool features